# Convert valid JSON to a Task<string>

Tags: c#, .net, json

I'm trying to mock `ReadAsStringAsync` on the top line for a unit test to return a Task where the string is the JSON below:

```
var jsonString = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
// convert to our OfferJsonRow format
var jsonData = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, List<OfferJsonRow>>>(jsonString);
var rawOfferData = jsonData["data"];
```

How do I convert this valid JSON to a `Task<string>`?

JSON:

```
{
    "data": [{
        "Latitude": "xxx",
        "RedemptionType": "barcode",
        "Version": "1",
        "HeaderType": "",
        "FontColour": "",
        "LogoType": "",
        "RedemptionLimit": "",
        "RedemptionTimeMinutes": ""
    }]
}
```

Here is my code:

```
var response = new Mock<HttpResponseMessage>();
response.Setup(rm => rm.Content.ReadAsStringAsync()).Returns(Task.Delay(10).ContinueWith(t => "Hello"));
```

I believe if I replace "Hello" with the JSON then it'll be what I want but it throws errors when pasting that JSON into Visual Studio Code

Comment: You're probably not escaping the quotes when pasting it in, would be my first guess

Comment: @Rob Yeah. So it that necessary? My JSON is actually huge, much bigger than what I entered here

Comment: You need to return `Task<string>` but instead returning `Task`. You can try return `Task.FromResult("Hello");`

Comment: Yes, it is necessary. You can't just paste in data without adhering to c# syntax. Replacing " with "" should be enough if you prefix your string with @

Comment: @Fabio Getting an error over "FromResult" - Task.FromResult<TResult>(TResult) Cannot be inferred from the usage - try specifying the type arguments explicitly. My attempt to specify type explicitely: `.Returns(Task<Task<string>>.FromResult(JSONString));` throwing `System.NotSupportedException`

Comment: Use 'Task.FromResult<string>("hello")'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the comments suggest, I had to escape the JSON initially just to get visual studio to accept it. eg:

```
  var JSONString =  ""Longitude"": ""xxx"",
            ""Latitude"": ""-xxx"",
            ""RedemptionType"": ""barcode"",
            ""Version"": ""1"",
            ""HeaderType"": """",
            ""FontColour"": """",
            ""LogoType"": """",
            ""RedemptionLimit"": """",
            ""RedemptionTimeMinutes"": """"
        }]
    }";
```

Then to use it as a json string that the client code expected, I had to unescape it:

```
var unescapedjson = Regex.Unescape(JSONString);
```

As for the `Task<string>`,  it became unnecessary to mock the `HttpResponseMessage` so it wasn't needed.

I used a real `HttpResponseMessage` and set its `content` field manually to `unescapedjson`:

```
var response = new HttpResponseMessage();
Microsoft.JScript.GlobalObject.unescape(JSONString);
response.Content = new StringContent(unescapedjson);
```

full code:

```
[Test]
public async Task AllPartners_HasPartners_GetsThem() {
 var response = new HttpResponseMessage();
 var unescapedjson = Regex.Unescape(JSONString);
 var unescapedjson2 = Microsoft.JScript.GlobalObject.unescape(JSONString);
 response.Content = new StringContent(unescapedjson);
 await _offersDataService.ProcessResponse(response);
 Assert.Greater(_offersDataService.AllPartners.Count, 0);
}
```